# Can we get windows phone device temprature, air pressure, humidity , Infrared Sensor in c#

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

Is there any way to check the following in windows phone 8.1?

1. Infrared Sensor
2. Windows phone device temperature.
3. Heart Rate, SPO2, and Uv Sensor
4. Pedometer

Answer (score 0):

1. No, there isn't an api for this.
2. System temperatures are handled by the OS, I don't see why you'd need this. Also, it isn't available.
3. These are accessible through the Band (2) SDK, found on http://developer.microsoftband.com/bandSDK
4. Again, available through the Band SDK, although I am not sure if Microsoft Health supports this without a Band.